# How "general" must a problem be to warrant use of a language/library tag?

Tags: discussion

I posted this question:

[AsyncContext response does not match original incoming request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711105/asynccontext-response-does-not-match-original-incoming-request)

Which was related to a web application written in Java, built on Spring MVC, and (in my opinion) focused on a Java EE class `AsyncContext`, and its proper use.

Another user and myself seem to be in disagreement as to when the use of library-related tags like `JavaEE`, and language tags like `Java`, is appropriate. (See [question revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27711105/revisions).)

If a problem/code snippet is written in a particular language, but is not necessarily a *language problem*, is the tag still acceptable? Are there any community guidelines as to where the line is drawn?

I don't mean to bolster support for my tag revisions, simply to better understand when these general tags apply to questions.

Comment: As a JavaEE person, this reads like a Java-related question to me. That being said, it is probably not related to the java code itself, but the environment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[@BradleyDotNet's answer is correct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281444/16587).  Except I'd remove the 'nearly' and just always include the language tag.

Tags serve a few purposes, not the least of which is to get eyeballs on your question. People may not think to follow the framework tag, but they'll definitely follow the language tag.

Solving the problem is what's important, not that a question isn't explicitly about a core language feature.

Comment: keep it as "always" as you want elsewhere, just please _please_ [don't add java tag to java-me questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281443/how-general-must-a-problem-be-to-warrant-use-of-a-language-library-tag/281448#comment135709_281448 "for the reasons explained eg here")

Answer (score 10):

You should nearly *always* tag with the general language tag. For starters, it tells readers what language answers are expected in, and helps the syntax highlighter.

For more selfish reasons, far more people are following the general language tags, so you miss a lot of visibility by not using the general tag.

Also, that wasn't a moderator you were "fighting" with, just a high-rep user.

Comment: That has been my understanding (and practice) since I joined nearly 6 years ago, but the back-and-forth that has ensued left me wondering. Thanks. (Also, thank you for clarifying moderator vs. high-rep user.)

Comment: @CraigOtis Unfortunately I'm not enough of a domain expert to comment on the specific question, but the java tag *seems* relevant as an outsider.